# Is the tangent bundle to the algebraic loop group of $GL_n$ ample?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

I am trying to understand the tangent bundle to *algebraic loop groups*, particularly for $G=GL_n$, over arbitrary characteristic. Can anyone point me to existing literature related to this? In particular, I want to figure out if the tangent bundle is ample. Does anyone know of existing ideas in this regard?

Comment: For an affine variety, any non-zero vector bundle is ample and $GL_n$ is affine.

Comment: @Mohan The question is about the tangent bundle of the loop group $LGL_n$ of $GL_n$.

Comment: @user1504 I am ignorant and did not even know that the loop group is an algebraic variety (and I do not know what ample means otherwise).

Comment: According to Faltings: http://www.ems-ph.org/journals/show_abstract.php?issn=1435-9855&vol=5&iss=1&rank=2 the algebraic loop group is an ind-affine group. Like Mohan, I do not know what an ample bundle on such a thing is.

Comment: It is an inductive limit of closed sub-varieties. So ample in this case means that the restriction of the bundle to every stratum is ample.